# Scale property not working for border on android 7.0 react-native

Tags: react-redux, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-navigation

i am trying to scale circle but its not working for android 7.0 it showing this beh see attached image.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2C90.png)

Actually i have two circles and on click i want to scale that circle and if that circle already scaled then scale back to that.
Below code is working fine on all devices expect android 7.0

```
const ScaleCircle = (props) => {
const { circleStyle, } = style;
const { unSelected, selected } = customStyle;
const { txt, pressEvent } = props;
let isSelected = txt.isSelected ? selected : unSelected;
let { fontSize, ...optStyle } = isSelected;

return (
    <TouchableHighlight
        style={[circleStyle, optStyle]}
        onPress={pressEvent}
    >
        <Text style={[{ fontSize: fontSize }]}>
            {txt.txt}
        </Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
);
```

};

export {ScaleCircle}

Here is style code

```
const customStyle = {
selected: {
    borderWidth: 4,
    zIndex: 2,
    fontSize: 25,
    marginLeft: 10,
    transform: [{ scale: 1.3 }],
    backgroundColor: LIGHTGREYCOLOR,
    position: 'relative'

},
unSelected: {
    marginLeft: 10,
    borderWidth: 2,
    fontSize: 20,
    zIndex: 1,
    position: 'relative',
    backgroundColor: WHITECOLOR,
    transform: [{ scale: 1 }]

},
circleStyle: {
    borderRadius: Math.round(SCREEN_WIDTH + SCREEN_HEIGHT) / 2,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderWidth: 2,
    padding: 5,
    width: SCREEN_WIDTH * 0.4,
    height: SCREEN_WIDTH * 0.4
},
```

}

Comment: please provide your code

Comment: same problem as here https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18208